# Passing LPWSTR as Reference in a method in C++

Tags: c++, hungarian-notation, lpwstr

I am passing LPWSTR as a reference in a method. The value remains in method but in callee function, it gets lost. I suspect I need to give some memory to LPWSTR but I am unable to figure out the method to do it.
This is how my code looks like:

```
ValidateUrl(LPCWSTR wzSomeUrl, LPWSTR& DecodeUrlOut) {

    /* 
     I decode wzSomeUrl and put value in DecodeurlOut
    */

}

LPWSTR DecodeUrlOut = NULL;
ValidateUrl(wzSomeUrl , DecodeUrlOut);
```

I debug and find that DecodeUrlOut's value is L"".

Comment: The problem is somewhere in the code you haven't shown. If I had to guess, I'd suspect you make `DecodeUrlOut` point to a local variable, which is destroyed when the function returns, leaving `DecodeUrlOut` a dangling pointer.

Comment: visit [a link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137672/passing-lpcwstr-by-reference.

Comment: @RohitHajare - Yeah this is same issue I am facing. I believe the problem is because of scopeof variable as mentioned in link you shared. Changing LPWSTR to wstring. Thanks for sharing the link. Will update if it works.

Comment: Changing the type of DecodeUrlOut to wstring fixed the issue for me. Thanks Rohit!!